# Why does my local video stream rotate during calls?

Tags: android, webrtc

We have a native `Android` `webrtc`-based voip app. Only in our `Android` app (as opposed to other platforms), the `local camera stream` is rotated after being in a call for a while. Usually it takes about 10 seconds. But sometimes more, even as much as a minute.
The `remote` will get the `stream` rotated as well, so it's not a `rendering` issue.
The `stream` is always rotated 90 degrees clockwise in `portrait orientation`, but is correct in one `landscape orientation` and upside down in the other `landscape orientation`.
After a while, the `stream` will be rotated back to the correct `orientation` again (and back to bugged after a while again).
I've tried several `revisions` ranging from early 8xxx to the latest (9125), all have the same problem. `Apprtc demo` has the problem as well. I've tested on several different phones (although only Samsung devices) and the problem exists on all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was faced with the same issue and I didn't found a right solution, but there is a workaround. I found that the reason of the rotation is cpu overuse detection, it leads to changing quality and it seems there is some bug in this functionality in android implementation. So I just added `peerConnectionConstraints.optional.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googCpuOveruseDetection", "false"));`
and it prevented this rotation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did the same, but I set it in the webrtc source before compiling. [Here is the issue](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=4933&thanks=4933&ts=1440067428) with some extra information. I'll mark yours as the answer as that will probably be the best solution for future readers.